# MySQL - UNHEX(HEX(UTF-8)) issue

Tags: mysql

I've got a database with UTF-8 characters in it, which are improperly displayed. I figured that I could use `UNHEX(HEX(column)) != column` condition to know what fields have UTF-8 characters in them. The results are rather interesting:

```
id        | content | HEX(content) | UNHEX(HEX(content)) LIKE '%c299%' | UNHEX(HEX(content)) LIKE '%FFF%' | UNHEX(HEX(content))
49829102  |         | C299         | 0                                 | 0                                | c299
874625485 | FFF     | 464646       | 0                                 | 1                                | FFF
```

How is this possible and, possibly, how can I find the row with this character in it?

-- edit(2): since my edit has been removed (probably when JamWaffles was fixing my beautiful data table), here it is again: as editor strips out UTF-8 characters, the content in first row is \uc299 (if that's not clear ;) )

-- edit(3): I've figured out what the issue is - the actual representation of `UNHEX(HEX(content))` is WRONG - to display my multibyte character I had to do the following: `SELECT UNHEX(SUBSTR(HEX(content),1)))`. Sadly UNHEX(C299) doesn't work as UNHEX(C2)+UNHEX(99) so it's back to the drawing board.

Comment: Please post the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for your table so we can see the schema. Also, please post the full query you ran to get those results.

Comment: @Ike Walker Sure:

table: `CREATE TABLE \`table\` (
 \`id\` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 \`content\` longtext NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=874625486 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

query: `SELECT id, content, HEX( content ) , UNHEX( HEX( content ) ) LIKE '%c299%', UNHEX( HEX( content ) ) LIKE '%FFF%', UNHEX( HEX( content ) ) FROM \`table\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to determine if a string contains UTF-8 specific characters. The first is to see if the string has values outside the ASCII character set:

```
SELECT _utf8 'amńbcd' REGEXP '[^[.NUL.]-[.DEL.]]';
```

The second is to compare the binary and character lengths:

```
SELECT LENGTH(_utf8 'amńbcd') <> CHAR_LENGTH(_utf8 'amńbcd');
```

Both return `TRUE`.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9811